# \/?' was unexpected at this time error in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, passwords, random-number-generator, password-generation

I am trying to integrate a password generator into my batch file so that it generates multiple passwords.

Unfortunately it give the following error:

```
\/?' was unexpected at this time.
```

The expected output is multiple (1000) lines of the form:

Random string is {password}

Where `{password}` consists of 32 random characters from the string `_Alphanumeric`.

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
set executecounter=0
setlocal
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789


:loop
(@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=32
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@()\/?'=-_+
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
Echo Random string is !_RndAlphaNum! >> D:\password2.txt
pause 

)
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="1000" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
endlocal
pause
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Yes you did :)) But this is different. This was to other one I told you about

Comment: Don't remember, it was from this site but it was before I made my account and since I closed the browser there ware no history left. I'll edit it a bit later cause I'm on a mobile connection, I need to go and make a new contract now :D

Comment: Anyways I've fixed it ;)

Comment: I've edited the question for you and answered with a corrected batch file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### /?' was unexpected at this time error in batch file.

This is because you have used brackets `(` and `)` to group multiple commands.

Your code contains the following:

```
(
...
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ... @()\/?'=-_+
)
```

This means that the wrong `)` (the one in the `set`) is matching the first opening `(`, hence the error.

In fact you don't need to use brackets `(` and `)` to group multiple commands if a couple of other small changes are made, which is to re-initialise some variables because you have a new outer loop in order to generate multiple passwords.

---

#### Fixed batch file:

```
@echo off

set executecounter=0
setlocal
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:loop

Set _RNDLength=32
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@()\/?'=-_+
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
SET _RndAlphaNum=
set _RND=
set _len=


:_LenLoop

IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=

:_loop

Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
Echo Random string is !_RndAlphaNum!>> d:\password2.txt

set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="1000" goto done
goto loop

:done

echo Complete!
endlocal
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I had to attend some other projects. Thanks for the help David, I'll give it a try and get back to you as soon as possible ;)

Comment: Damn, it works like a charm and, it just as I thought, it works extremely faster then the previous code (it generated the 1000 strings in under 10 minutes). It's gonna make a fine tool for pen-testing word listing!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PowerShell for something much simpler?

```
$randomObj = New-Object System.Random
$NewPassword=""
1..12 | ForEach { $NewPassword = $NewPassword + [char]$randomObj.next(33,126) }
$NewPassword
```

Comment: I never used PowerShell. It dosen't look to user friendly for me...

Comment: @Unix give it a shot. It's object oriented so takes a little bit to get used to. That script does essentially:
1. Create an object of type System.Random
2. Create a variable called $NewPassword as a string 
3. Loop 12 times, each time adding a random character to the empty string
4. Display the resulting string